# Finding primers on fasta files with position, line and column information

Tags: grep, bash-scripting

I've some [fasta files](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/fastaformat/) which contain exactly 80 columns per line. Forget about the definition line that starts `>` and consider the rest that has around 1250000 lines. I needed to find some primers like `CAATCGCCGT` and their position, line, and column. I've converted all lines into a single line then used the `grep` to find their position in the Bash script.

```
grep -o -P -b -n CAATCGCCGT input.fasta
```

that outputs `3:3206721:CAATCGCCGT` in this format on the original file.

What I need now, show the line and column number in the original fasta file like

```
 3:3206721[40084:1]:CAATCGCCGT      #that is just `div 80` and `mod 80` see below

 3:3206721[3206721 / 80:3206721 % 80]:CAATCGCCGT
```

A sample fasta;

```
ATCCATTTGTCTTTCCCTCAATCGCCGTGCTCCTTATAAACAATCGCCTTCGGTGTACCCCTGTTAGGCG
CGTACGAATGTATCTGCGGTGAGTCGAAAGTGAGAGCTCCGCCTGCCAGAAGCCTTCCTGCTGCAACCAA
TCGCCGTGAGTATGACAAATTCATTTTCAAACAACCTGCCCCCTACGATCCGACTCCGACTCTCATTCCC
AATTCCGGCAAATCCCTGTGTGCATGTCAACCCCCGGAGGGAAGCACACATTTCCTTGCGGAAGAAAGTT
AGCTTTGGCCGGCCGTCGTCTTCTTGCCTTCCGGGATTTGCCCGTCCCCGGTGGGGATGCCCTAACGGTA
TCAAATTGGTGACGTTTCAAATCGTTTGCAATCAATCGCCGTCCAGCTGCATAACTTGGGGCGCGTTTCG
```

I cannot simply get the output of the `grep` and divide it with 80 and take the mod. I need a solution for this and a solution working directly on the fasta file is better, since there is no need to convert the input into a line. Both are fine.

In the sample input, there is an occurrence of the primer that stands on two lines the others are not divided.

Comment: This Perl module could help you: https://metacpan.org/dist/TIGR/view/lib/TIGR/FASTA/Reader.pm Have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553004/372239

Comment: @Toto great, thanks for the links.

Comment: The [so] link is about extracting position that is not my case. I'm searching tag [fasta] there,

Comment: @Toto Biostar was easier to use. I've written an answer that works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked and the easiest solution is from [Biostar](https://www.biostars.org/) that is implemented in Perl.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $usage = "perl dnamotif.pl <fasta file> <primers file>";
my $fasta_filename = shift(@ARGV) or die("Usage: $usage $!");
my $pfile = shift(@ARGV) or die("Usage: $usage $!");
my $start = 0;
my $motifCounter=1; 

my $fasta_parser = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $fasta_filename, -format => 'Fasta');



while(my $seq_obj = $fasta_parser->next_seq())
{
    printf("Searching sequence '%s'...\n", $seq_obj->id);

    open my $info, $pfile or die "Could not open primers $pfile: $!";

    while( my $motif = <$info>)  {   
        chomp $motif;
        printf("\n[%2s Looking motif [%s]]\n", $motifCounter, $motif);    
        $start = 0;

        while((my $pos = index($seq_obj->seq(), $motif, $start)) != -1) {

            printf("\nmotif found at position %8d ", $pos + 1);
            printf("[%8d,%8d]", ((($pos)/70))+1, (($pos) % 70)+1);
            $start = $pos + 1;
        
        }
        
        $motifCounter++;
        printf("\n");
    
    }
    close $info;

}
```

I've found the base code on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325909/1820553) and modified it to my needs ( I had 80 primers to search). I've put it here for anyone's needs. The partial output of the actual file is;

```
Searching sequence 'ref|NW_024108998.1|:1-6077679'...

[ 1 Looking motif [CAATCGCCGT]]


[ 2 Looking motif [TTCCGAACCC]]

motif found at position   660830 [    9441,      30]
motif found at position   788016 [   11258,      26]
motif found at position  1349822 [   19284,      12]
```

Comment: AFAIK `printf` is less efficient than  simple `print`

Comment: For the possible users of this code, I've tested and verified this with grep after converting a fasta into a  one line.