# Is there a limit for a line length for grep command to process correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

While I'm checking the results of [my biostar implementation](https://superuser.com/a/1702854/428106) for searching primes in a fasta file, I've seen a strange result. I've originally a 70 column file and converted it into a file that has 6077828 characters in a single line.

When I used the grep command

`grep -o -P -b -n CAATCGCCGT fasta.txt`

It displays two matches that are not displayed in my Biostar implementation.

```
3:3206721:CAATCGCCGT
3:4140348:CAATCGCCGT
```

I've searched the primer with Kate on the original file and have not found it. It might possible that the primer spreads into two lines due to the 70 column division of the text.

Then I've converted them to line and column numbers with div and mod

- 3206572 represents line 45808 and column 12
- 4140199 represents line 59145 and column 49

The primer, however, was not there.

Is there a limit to the max line that grep can process? If so, when the limit exceeds, are the results are reliable up to the limit size?

---

- My sample file can be accessed on [github](https://github.com/kelalaka153/Search-primers-on-fasta-files/blob/main/dna-rna.txt)
- An, the one-line file [there](https://github.com/kelalaka153/Search-primers-on-fasta-files/blob/main/allInOneLineHeaderless.txt), too.

Comment: (1) Where did `3206572` and `4140199` come from? They are connected to `3206721` and `4140348` from the output of `grep`, the increment is `149` former-to-former and latter-to-latter; but I don't get the point of it. (2) I downloaded the two linked files. `<allInOneLineHeaderless.txt tr -dc 'CGAT' | wc -c` yields `6077679`; `<dna-rna.txt tr -dc 'CGAT' | wc -c` yields `6077410`. Note `C`, `G`, `A` or `T` in the headers can make the second number greater than the first; but it's lower! How? (3) I answered about `grep`, but probably you're barking up the wrong tree. Re-check the files.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for the reply. I'm trying to verify my results. 3206572 and the other is the location of the pattern output from grep. I'm sorry about the header that I've omitted that number `149` comes from. Now, with your comment and answer, I've looked at the one-line file with `nano`and see that it can process it, too. It produced the same results. I'm searching for the original file with the kate editor but produces no result. You might be right that I'm on the wrong tree. Thanks, again. I'll double-check the files.

Comment: Ok, now I can verify the results. Made a fresh start and saw that I can have the same results. I got only one DNA file, however, I'm not sure how they corrupted (maybe later I can investigate). Thanks again.

Comment: A HOWTO versoin: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-big-binary-file/758528#758528

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In general

The [POSIX specification of `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) states that

> INPUT FILES
> The input files shall be text files.

It means `grep` must reliably handle text files (["shall" means "mandatory behavior"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap01.html)). Files that are not text files may or may not be handled reliably, the behavior is not specified.

A "text file" here [means](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) [emphasis mine]:

> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length, including the <newline> character. Although POSIX.1-2017 does not distinguish between text files and binary files (see the ISO C standard), **many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN or INPUT FILES sections.**

`{LINE_MAX}` is explained [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html):

> `{LINE_MAX}`
> Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files. The length includes room for the trailing <newline>.
> Minimum Acceptable Value: `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`

> `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`
> Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files. The length includes room for the trailing <newline>.
> Value: 2048

All this means that an implementation of `grep` may mishandle lines longer than `{LINE_MAX}` for the given system and one can still call it "portable". `{LINE_MAX}` may be as low as 2048.

Keep in mind that it's not like someone came up with the specification and the maintainers of different implementations of `grep` struggle to conform. It's rather the other way around: the existing major implementations have been examined, the common set of features found and documented. It might be some needed to catch up a little. Some may be way more powerful; and some may have been considered non-major from the very beginning, less capable for any reason, with reasons not to catch up.

One way or another you can expect `grep` shipped with a [POSIX-oriented OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems) (like Linux) and especially with a POSIX-certified OS (like macOS) to reliably handle lines up to 2048 bytes in length that do not contain NUL characters. If `grep` can handle longer lines then treat it as a bonus.

The general answer to "is there a limit for a line length?" is: yes, there may be, it's implementation-dependent; but if there's a limit, it should be at least 2048 bytes. The behavior for longer lines is unspecified.

---

#### In particular

You tagged [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu). Ubuntu ships with GNU `grep`. GNU `grep` [claims this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Introduction):

> Though `grep` expects to do the matching on text, it has no limits on input line length other than available memory, and it can match arbitrary characters within a line.