# Build tool spawns a daemon that does not close its standard output. How can I prevent this from stalling my shell pipeline?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, daemon, stdout

I am using a (closed-source) vendor-specific build tool (Microsemi Designer, an
FPGA layout tool). I invoke it from a shell script (highly simplified):

```
...  # Setup

/opt/.../designer SCRIPT:my_script.tcl |tee build.log

...  # Postprocessing
```

The problem is: even after the `designer` process terminates, the `tee` process
keeps running, and thus the script does not continue.

As far as I understand, this is because `designer` spawns a long-lived daemon,
`windu_scmd50`, and that daemon does not close its standard output (which it
inherits from `designer`). So `tee` is waiting for an EOF on its standard input
(connected to the pipe) which never comes.

Evidence that this is the cause of the problem:

- `ps` shows that the tee process is still running, but the designer process
  is not.
- When I kill the `windu_scmd50` process, `tee` terminates immediately and the
  script continues (but I cannot do this in production).
- If I don't pipe the output of `designer` to `tee` (or to anything else; the same thing happens with `cat` in place of `tee`), the
  script does not stall.
- If I run `designer` from Jenkins (without piping the output to a file),
  Jenkins notifies me that the "Process leaked file descriptors", linking to
  [this help page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) (apparently, Jenkins explicitly deals with this
  situation).

So: **How can I ensure that the `tee` process terminates when (or shortly after)
the `designer` process does?**

Some approaches I have considered:

- Is it possible to redirect stdout of a running process?
- Is there a tool that I can use in lieu of a shell pipe, that will detect the
  termination of the `designer` process?

Some approaches that are not possible:

- I can't ignore the output from the `designer` process; I need to write it to
  a log file.
- I can't kill the `windu_scmd50` process because it might be used by other
  processes on the machine.
- The workarounds described on [the Jenkins help page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) don't seem to apply
  because they would also silence the output from `designer`.
- I can't modify the tool installation to replace the `windu_scmd50`
  executable with a wrapper.

Some more notes:

- Logging output from the `windu_scmd50` process would be nice, but is not a requirement. I do, however, need to log the output from the designer process.
- In practice, there's another filter between `designer` and `tee` that adds timestamps (`designer ... |ts -s |tee build.log`)
- Using `bash`-specific features is acceptable; compatibility with `sh` is not a requirement

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (`test.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"
sleep 10 &    # Background process that does not close stdout
echo "End"
```

Calling this script directly (`./test.sh`) prints "Start" and "End" and finishes
immediately. Piping the output to another process (`./test.sh |cat`) prints
"Start" and "End" immediately, but then pauses for 10 seconds before it
finishes.

Comment: You might be able to avoid the pipe by using process substitution with input redirection. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53382807/165358).

Comment: @harrymc That does not appear to work - using `cat < <(./test.sh)` with the example from the question still pauses for 10 seconds after it prints "End".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple workaround is to inject a message to the stream after the `designer` process terminates. A `cat`-like filter preceding `tee` should exit when it encounters the message.

It will be something like:

```sh
{ /opt/.../designer SCRIPT:my_script.tcl; echo message; } \
| sed -n '/^message$/q;p' | tee build.log
```

Notes:

- If `designer` (or anything that inherits its stdout) prints the message then `sed` will quit prematurely. Choose a `sTr1ng_Unlik3ly t0-Be enCOUnTered_in vvhat designer PRinT5`. The ASCII EOT character (octal 004) may be a good choice:
  `{ …; printf '\004\n'; } | sed -n "/^$(printf '\004')\$/q;p" | …`
- There are limits to what `sed` can handle. See [this answer about `grep`](https://superuser.com/a/1703052/432690), it's similar with `sed`.
- `^message$` matches a full line containing `message` only. This assumes the output (if any) from the `designer` process ends with a newline character (i.e. the last line is complete; see [*line*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) vs [*incomplete line*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195)); only then `message` will be in its own line. If `designer` generates an incomplete line for sure then you want `sed -n '/message$/{s/message$//;p;q};p'`. If it can be either way then you want `sed -n '/^message$/q;/message$/{s/message$//;p;q};p'`. Note the incomplete line from `designer` will become a complete line.
- Non-silent descendants of `designer` may interfere:

  - They may cause `message` to appear mid-line (even if they try to output complete lines). For our `sed` it will be as if `designer` generated an incomplete line.
  - If your chosen message is very long then it may appear in the pipe interleaved with other data (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574167/10765659) and [`PIPE_BUF` here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)). In such case our `sed` won't detect it at all.

Comment: Nice use of sed! I haven't tested it in production yet, but this should be a feasible workaround. One caveat, though: if the daemon process tries to output anything after sed terminates, it receives SIGPIPE.