# How to find the "pattern" in FASTA file and record the cordinates along with header

Tags: bash, python, shell-script, awk, perl

I am looking for a solution to search for a string of 17 base pairs in the FASTA file that is the human reference genome.
To clarify, in simple words and put the resources, i have tried grep function to count the frequency of the "pattern".

Sample reference file example:

```
>chr1 CP068277.2 Homo sapiens isolate CHM13 chromosome 1
CaccctaaaccctaaccGTACATAAAATATGAAAcctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccctaaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccct
aaccctaaccctaacccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctGTACATAAAATATGAAAaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccGTACATAAAATATGAAAtaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccct
aaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaa
ccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaGTACATAAAATATGAAAaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaGTACATAAAATATGAAAccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaa
```

i Used this method to count if pattern exist,

```
grep -i "GTACATAAAATATGAAA" ref.fa |wc -l
```

This code gives me the outcome as 49678.
But this is for full search, in reference example i have intentionally added 5 stretches that is in capital letters.

Further i used,

```
grep -o -P -b -n -i "GTACATAAAATATGAAA" ref.fa
```

Outcome was : 35659119:2888387418:gtacataaaatatgaaa

Probably, it's coordinates and the stretch itself without a header.

What I need as the outcome is the following:

| chromosome | start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | x position | y position |
| chr1 | x1 position | y1 position |

So here, chr1 is an example header and in reality, my fasta file will contain 23 chromosomes and its own FASTA lines.

I hope i could explain my query, but if not then i will try to elaborate more.
Thank you.

Comment: (1) It would be easier if you had 23 *separate* files. (2) I know nothing about chromosomes and FASTA files. Are newline characters meaningful? My point is `grep` will not detect the sequence if it starts in one line and ends in the next line. Is it OK?

Comment: Hi Thank you, let us consider i have 23 files, i can seperate it out and divide into 23 parts. so then in one file line is like >name, next line ATCGCGATCGTAC......etc for many characters may be 1 million bases. FASTA files format is like this.

Comment: (2 again) I can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) that most newline characters are arbitrary. Is it true? My point is if you use `grep` to search for `AAA` and there is a line that ends with `CGA` followed by a line that begins with `AAT` then you won't find `AAA` there. If you concatenate the lines then yes, now you will. I want to know if we should concatenate all the non-header lines within each chromosome, so there will be one long line per chromosome. [GNU `grep` should be able to deal with long lines](https://superuser.com/a/1703052/432690).

Comment: I see now what you meant, thank you. in reality now i am not concerned about this as real dataset has line >header and then multiple lines that is 60 characters in each line. Obviously my estimation of pattern will be underestimation as these patterns could be splitted into two different lines. But that is ok. At this moment, with the above setting i need something that identifies ">" as header of line until next ">", searches the pattern, captures respective header and reports the start and end position. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "x position" and "y position"? Is it line number within the input file and offset within the line where the pattern matched?

Comment: So x1 and y1 position would be (x1 that is start of the pattern) and y1 is the end position (x+stretch). in all cases the distance is measured from the first character of the line below ">" header line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited to add case insensitive matching]

Try the following code

```perl
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


# first commandline parameter is the pattern to match
my $want = shift @ARGV ;

my $chromosome ;

while (<>)
{
    # match lines that start with a ">" and remember the first word
    $chromosome = $1
        if /^>(\w+)/ ;

    while (/($want)/gi)
    {
        # remember the length of the matched string
        my $match = length $1;

        # "@-" stores the offsets to each of the submatches
        # "$-[0]" is the first one, namely the offset to the start that we need
        my $start = $-[0];

        # work out the offset for the end of the match
        my $end = $start + $match - 1 ;

        print "$chromosome\t$start\t$end\n";
    }

}
```

assuming the data is in `ref.fa` contains

```
>chr1 CP068277.2 Homo sapiens isolate CHM13 chromosome 1
CaccctaaaccctaaccGTACATAAAATATGAAAcctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccctaaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccct
aaccctaaccctaacccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctGTACATAAAATATGAAAaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccGTACATAAAATATGAAAtaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccct
aaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaa
ccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaGTACATAAAATATGAAAaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaGTACATAAAATATGAAAccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaa
```

running the code gives

```
$ perl try.pl GTACATAAAATATGAAA ref.fa
chr1    17      33
chr1    55      71
chr1    107     123
chr1    23      39
chr1    137     153
```

If you need to get the true offsets into the sequences (i.e. by concatenating all the sequence lines together), the script can be changed as follows

```perl
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# enable paragraph mode
local $/ = '';

my $want = shift @ARGV ;

my $chromosome ;

while (<>)
{
    # get the lines in the paragraph
    my @lines = split "\n", $_;

    # first line is the title
    my $title = shift @lines;

    # only want paragraphs where the first lines begins with a ">"
    next
        if ! /^>(\w+)/ ;

    # remember the first word
    $chromosome = $1 ;

    # concatenate the "sequence" lines into a single string with no newlines
    my $full_sequence = join "", @lines;

    while ($full_sequence =~ /($want)/gi)
    {
        # remember the length of the matched string
        my $match = length $1;

        # @- srores the offsets to each of the submatches
        # $-[0] is the first one
        my $start = $-[0];

        # work out the offset for the end of the match
        my $end = $start + $match - 1 ;

        print "$chromosome\t$start\t$end\n";
    }
}
```

running that gives

```
$ perl try.pl GTACATAAAATATGAAA ref.fa
chr1    17      33
chr1    232     248
chr1    284     300
chr1    554     570
chr1    668     684
```

Comment: Seems working on the string, i was wondering how i may be able to make pattern search case insensitive?

Comment: It works, just need to add the line# add the /i modifier to make the search case insensitive
$want = qr/$want/i; before line my $chromosome ;  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Updated answer to include case insensitive matching